# Few questions on customizing ListView

Tags: qt, listview, layout, qml

Here's what I've in my QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Test Window"

    ListView{
        id: listView
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        model: testContext.List
        interactive: false
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            width: parent.width
            leftPadding: 3
            rightPadding: scroll.width
            topPadding: 3
            bottomPadding: 3
            /*
            padding: {
                leftPadding: 3
                rightPadding: scroll.width
                topPadding: 3
                bottomPadding: 3
            }
            padding:{
                left: 3
                right: scroll.width
                top: 3
                bottom: 3
            }
            */
            contentItem: RowLayout{
                Text{ text: modelData.name }
                Text{
                    text: modelData.isActive
                    Layout.alignment: Text.AlignLeft
                }
                Text{
                    text: modelData.age
                    Layout.alignment: Text.AlignRight
                }
            }
            background: Rectangle{
                width: parent.width - scroll.width + 5
                color: hovered? "gray" : highlighted? "green" : modelData.isActive? "lightblue" : "white"
            }
            highlighted: ListView.isCurrentItem
            onClicked: listView.currentIndex = index
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{id: scroll; width: 15}
    }
}
```

The `c++` code is almost same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622656/why-doesnt-combobox-show-the-selected-item). All that I've changed is added one more boolean `PROPERTY` in `AClass`:

```
class AClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    PROPERTY(QString, name)
    PROPERTY(int, age)
    PROPERTY(bool, isActive)
};
```

and in the constructor of ViewModel's `.cpp` file (i.e. `Test Class`) added this `a->setisActive(i % 2 == 0);` line before adding it in `PROPERTY` named `List`.

**First problem:** why do I have to define `left/right/top/bottomPadding` separately? I've tried to define all 4 `padding: {...}` inside braces BUT none of those `commented out` part work.

**Second problem:** if I put that `ListView` in another QML file instead of `main.qml` I can replace `onClicked: listView.currentIndex = index` with `onClicked: currentIndex = index`, I don't have to give it an `id` and can load that in a loader with a button click without any error in output. Why is it necessary to give it an `id` if I put it in `main.qml`?

**Third problem:** the `ListView` looks like this:

[image]

the second column isn't aligned properly although I've `Layout.alignment: Text.AlignLeft` in that `Text`! I've tried by setting a fixed width for the first `Text` (i.e. modelData.name) BUT that doesn't work.

**EDIT**

I've added `Layout.preferredWidth` and `Layout.alignment` for all 3 `Text`:

```
contentItem: RowLayout{
    Text{
        id: nameText
        text: modelData.name
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width / 3
        Layout.alignment: Text.AlignRight
    }
    Text{
        text: modelData.isActive
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width / 3
        Layout.alignment: Text.AlignRight

    }
    Text{
        text: modelData.age
        Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width / 3
        Layout.alignment: Text.AlignRight    
    }
}
```

Now all columns are left aligned instead of right:

[image]

Why it is so?

Comment: [padding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#padding-prop) is a number, not group property, your commented code is syntactically incorrect. from the link above: _To specify a padding value for a specific edge of the control, set its relevant property - leftPadding ..._. Ad for `id` - it's good practice  using id  always if you refer to an item in the tree.

Comment: Incorrect aligning - you never set width of the column, just use `Layout.preferredWidth`

Comment: @folibis, well `Layout.preferredWidth` in all 3 `Text` forces all columns to be aligned Left! See Edit part.

Comment: you have to use alignment of the Text item itself - probably [Text.verticalAlignment / Text.horizontalAlignment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#verticalAlignment-prop).There is no sense to align the `Text` item since it fits all the column's width.

Comment: @folibis, yes, `horizontalAlignment = Text.AlignRight` solves the alignment problem and I also have to consider `scroll.width` in setting `Layout.preferredWidth` for perfect positioning.